# Angular Material mat-card width as inner text width

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, angular-material

Card's width is always 100%.

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/angular/xvknedbrppo?file=app%2Fcard-overview-example.ts)

I would adapt mat-card width to fit text width ( with some padding )

`<mat-card>Simple card</mat-card>`

Comment: what is the issue ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should apply to `mat-card` the css I wrote below.

```
mat-card{
    width: fit-content;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply write some css for mat-card and set the width property as you wish.
As example:

```
mat-card {
  width: 50%;
}
```